# Simulink backwards compatibility

Tags: simulink, backwards-compatibility

I implemented a (medium to big) simulink model in v2012b.
I thought it would work also in 2010bSP2, but it didn't. Some mask blocks are not opening and other strange errors.

In previous versions of simulink there was a "save as simulink 201x" model to force compatibility, but I couldn't find it anymore in 2012b.

Any clues on how to avoid rework?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with 2012b, and the new interface, they have moved the option to the menu:

File / Export Model to / Previous Version

The feature never seems to fully work, and I often get warnings when first loading a model into an older version, so I would recommend giving your model a thorough check over and test. I always save again from the correct version, to clear the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The refactoring for a New Simulink Version can show up at several points.

- Your own libraries: There is a feature called ["Forwarding Tables"](http://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2012/08/01/upgrading-simulink-libraries-with-forwarding-tables-and-transformation-functions/) that allows you to specify where a block in the new library is (I suppose you will have to refactor your libraries as well, and probably someone else uses those libraries too)
- It sounds like a biiig hack (and it is) but i found it sometimes the path of lowest resistantce... Just open your model in the Editor of your choice and replace the block paths whith the common refactoring funcitons. It is terrible i know but Simulink really lacks of refactoring functions...